# Google Drive Google Doc file type icons

Tags: google-drive-api

in the documentation of the Googel Drive SDK there is talked about the Google Drive icons, but what about the icons needed to show the different file tpyes that are from type Google Doc. The google spreadsheet icon, google presentation icon, etc.? Is it possible to get them and use them in our Google Drive Android-client?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While not available at the moment (sorry), these are coming soon (yay)!

p.s. right now you can probably extract them from from the Drive clients .ico files.

Comment: Do you know if we are allowed to use the icons?

Answer (score 0):

but file/folder metadata also contains *iconLink* field, where you can download item icon.

e.g.

{

```
 "kind": "drive#file",

 "iconLink": "https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_10_excel_list.png",
```

}

Comment: but they are not really small ones